# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3982,2) into shape (3982)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a python list (of length 206) of numpy arrays of shape (3982, 2) and would just like to convert the whole thing to a numpy array, but I am getting this error when trying to cast it. I know this should be really easy, but I am having trouble finding the right method to use for this. I get super confused when dealing with multidimensional arrays and having them in a list is giving me the biggest headache. Thanks.

Comment: What do you want the shape of the output to be? (206, 3982, 2)?

Comment: @Dennis yes as a numpy array

Comment: Can you not just do `numpy.array(your_list)`?

Comment: @Dennis no that raises the ValueError

Comment: This worked for me: `L = [numpy.zeros((2, 3)) for x in range(5)]; numpy.array(L)`. What's different?

Comment: @Dennis `type(my_list)` gives `list`. `len(my_list)` gives `206`. `type(my_list[0])` gives `numpy.ndarray`. And `my_list[0].shape` gives `(3982, 2)` so I dont really know

Comment: Perhaps your arrays have different shapes. What does `{arr.shape for arr in my_list}` give?

Comment: @Dennis oh my god literally one of them is (3982, 1) *facepalm*